# Segmentation fault in while loop. Valgrind doesnt find errors

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, valgrind, realloc

I appear to be getting a segmentation fault, but I can't figure out where or why it occurs. Any input would be helpful. 
I'm basically trying to read an input as chars, store them into word until I hit a space, and when I hit a space, store that word into a wordList. 
All this has to be done without ever storing in memory (must use dynamic allocation).

The relevant code is:

```
  char* word;
  int WFactor = 30;
  int WLFactor = 30;
  char** wordList;
  int wordCount = 0;
  int letterCount = 0;
  word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * WFactor);
  wordList = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * WLFactor);

  if( word == NULL ){
    free(word);
    free(wordList);
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation Failure");
    exit(1);
  }
  if(wordList == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation Failure");
    exit(1);
  }

  char cur = '*';
  while(cur!=EOF){ 
    if(letterCount == WFactor){
      WFactor = WFactor * 2;
      word = realloc(word, sizeof(char)*WFactor);
      if(word == NULL){

        free(word);
        free(wordList);
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory Re-Allocation Failure");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    cur = getchar();

    if(cur!=EOF && cur!= ' '){
      putchar(cur);
      word[letterCount] = cur;
      letterCount++;
    }

    if(cur == ' '){

    if(wordCount == WLFactor){
       WLFactor = WLFactor*2;
       wordList = realloc(wordList, sizeof(char*)*WLFactor);
       if(wordList == NULL){
         free(word);
         free(wordList);
         fprintf(stderr, "Memory Re-Allocation Failure");
         exit(1);
       }
    }

    printf("%s", "e");

    wordList[wordCount] = word;
    wordCount++;
    letterCount =0;
    word = NULL;
    WFactor = 19;
    printf("HERE");
    word = malloc(sizeof(char)*WFactor);

    if(word == NULL){
      free(wordList);
      fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation Failure");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where the fault occurs is important. Which line?

Comment: it doesnt say what line the fault occurs in

Comment: That's where your debugger comes into play. It'll tell you where it crashed. Otherwise it's anyone's guess.

Comment: Worth to read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

[`getchar()` returns `int` not `char`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.6).

If you assign its result to `char` it is not possible to safely detect ^EOF`.

To fix this change

```
char cur = '*';
```

to be

```
int cur = '*';
```